# Place order from suiteCRM and redirect into magento for payment

Tags: magento, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to create one functionality in suiteCRR which is below.

- Order place from the suiteCRM
- When i click on place order button on suiteCRM then it will redirect into magento website with that order informations.
- payment will be processed through magento only.

Any SuiteCRM guys help me would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create and "after_save" logic hook to redirect to where ever you need it to go once the record is saved in SuiteCRM.